# OAuth2 code to front-end from back-end not working

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I've been trying to implement OAuth2 for Google Sign-in with Vue and Deno, these are the relevant endpoints / domains

**Back-end**: `localhost:8182`
**Front-end**: `localhost:8080`

This is the flow of my setup: on the Vue front-end I fetch an authorization URI from the back-end, I've created this authorization URI with http://localhost:8080 as a redirect URI. Once the user signs in I get directed back to the Vue front-end with the authorization code in the URL.

Now I want to turn my authorization code into an access token, so using JavaScript I fetch the code from the URL and forward it to the back-end verification endpoint http://localhost:8182/oauth/validate, but it returns this error:

> Invalid authorization response: Redirect path should match configured
> path, but got: /oauth/validate

I figure that it errors out since I had the redirect URI set to `http://localhost:8080` but I'm trying to get the token from `/oauth/validate`, I've also included my Google Cloud Console authorized URIs.

[image: Google Cloud Console authorized URIs]

How can I fix this? In another post I saw someone using the same logic (sending the code from the front-end to the back-end and awaiting the result). But I must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `/oauth/validate`? I have a similar case in my local application. Here is how the "Authorized redirect URIs" section looks like:

[image: Authorized redirect URIs]

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sadly when I remove the path from the authorized redirect URIs I get this error from Google "The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:5000/login, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client." So I have to include the path :(